# Updating the value of a TextBlock on the basis of value of another TextBock in WPF using Dependency property

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

In my XAML i m having following two textBlocks

```
 <TextBlock Name="tbGeneratedSignature" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="2,2,0,0" Height="auto" Width="390"  Foreground="Black" TextDecorations="None" VerticalAlignment="Top" Focusable="False"/>


<TextBlock Name="tbSignatureText" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="5" Height="auto" Width="440" Foreground="Black"  />
```

On the basis of **tbGeneratedSignature.Text** i want to assign the same value to  **tbSignatureText.Text** using XAML only rather than using C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<TextBlock Name="tbGeneratedSignature" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="2,2,0,0" Height="auto" Width="390"  Foreground="Black" TextDecorations="None" VerticalAlignment="Top" Focusable="False"/>


<TextBlock Name="tbSignatureText" Text="{Binding ElementName=tbGeneratedSignature, Path=Text}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="5" Height="auto" Width="440" Foreground="Black"  />
```

Answer (score 1):

have you considered binding?

```
<TextBlock Name="tbSignatureText" 
           Text="{Binding ElementName=tbGeneratedSignature, Path=Text, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
           TextWrapping="Wrap" 
           Margin="5" 
           Height="auto" 
           Width="440" 
           Foreground="Black"  />
```

Comment: Thanks for the simple and efficient way

Comment: working fine even if i m not writing UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged

Comment: Yea I wasn't sure if the default binding for a `TextBlock` is `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` or if its `LostFocus`. When you bind to a `TextBox`'s `Text` property it defaults to `UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus`, so you have to change it to `PropertyChanged`